# Apache2 on Debian: Getting forbidden when accessing local website

Tags: apache-2.2

So I want to configure the folder /home/web as my webserver because I have folders there representing all the sites I'm developing. I recently switched from Centos to Debian so I'm reinstalling everything.

My current webpage is fh. The permissions are as follows (This is inside /home/web:

```
drwxrwxr-x.  6 ariela www-data 4096 May 15 06:33 fh
```

I've modified /etc/apache2/apach2.conf so that the default /var/www/html dir looks like this:

```
<Directory /home/web>
        Order allow,deny
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

After that I've changed /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf to read like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
        # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
        # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
        # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
        # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
        # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
        # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
        #ServerName www.example.com

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /home/web

        # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
        # error, crit, alert, emerg.
        # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
        # modules, e.g.
        #LogLevel info ssl:warn

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
        # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
        # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
        # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
        # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
        #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>
```

But after all of that redirecting my browser to localhost/fh I get the Forbidden message and the log shows:

```
[Wed May 15 07:24:53.129930 2019] [authz_core:error] [pid 8159] [client ::1:56998] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /home/web/fh
[Wed May 15 07:24:53.183159 2019] [authz_core:error] [pid 8159] [client ::1:56998] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /home/web/favicon.ico, referer: http://localhost/fh
```

What am I missing?

Comment: You're missing the typo `/howe/web` in your `<Directory /howe/web>` line.

Comment: You are right. But I fixed it and nothing changed. Same error. Same forbidden

Comment: You *did* reload apache after making the fix, right? Otherwise it might be an selinux thing (I have little experience with that).

Comment: I did (systemctl restart apache2). There is no sel linux far as I know in debian. I did have that problem in centos. But debian does not have it.

Comment: I've also checked that the correction was done, and it is correct now, but still no dice... It's weird I've never had so many problems making this work...

Comment: The fact that there is a dot after the `...r-x` in your `ls -l` output suggests selinux, or at the least extended attributes.

Comment: Ok. And how would I go about checking any of this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93675/discussion-between-wurtel-and-aarelovich).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is twofold:

- You had a typo in the Directory name (howe vs. home)
- You had added a line `Order allow,deny` which is the old style of access control, and that expects a corresponding `allow from all` type of rule, not the new `Require all granted`

So fix the typo, remove the Order line, and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

First off, you should add your `<Directory>` block to your `<VirtualHost>` configuration. It should not be necessary to edit `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`.

#### Apache 2.2

If you're using Apache 2.2, then `Require all granted` is invalid syntax.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_access_compat.html#order

> `Deny,Allow`
>
> First, all [Deny](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_access_compat.html#deny) directives are evaluated; if any match, the request is denied **unless** it also matches an [Allow](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_access_compat.html#allow) directive. Any requests which do not match any [Allow](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_access_compat.html#allow) or [Deny](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_access_compat.html#deny) directives are permitted.

So if we use `Order Deny,Allow` here and don't specify any `Allow` or `Deny` rules, then access is allowed.

```
<Directory /home/web>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>
```

Alternative:

```
<Directory /home/web>
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>
```

#### Apache 2.4

If you're using an Apache 2.4, then `Order`, `Allow` and `Deny` are deprecated syntax. Use `Require` instead:

```
<Directory /home/web>
    Require all granted
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>
```

See: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/upgrading.html#run-time